# python watchdog invoke class method when event happend

Tags: python, class, reference, watchdog

I am using watchdog to get notified when a certain file is changed,

evertything worked as long as i am using no classes like so

```
class MyEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        super(MyEventHandler, self).on_modified(event)
        logging.info("File %s was just modified" % event.src_path)
        readConfigFile()

def readConfigFile():
    # set certain values here

def main():
    while True:
        # using values from configFile here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    # do something else
```

but if i put some classes in place i don't know how to call the method then setup is like this now

```
class MyEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        super(MyEventHandler, self).on_modified(event)
        logging.info("File %s was just modified" % event.src_path)
        readConfigFile()  #<- i want to call this method in class Configuration

class Configuration:
    def readConfigFile(self):
         # set certain values here
    def provideValues(self):
         # get certain values here

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conf = Configuration()
        event_handler = MyEventHandler(patterns=patterns)

    def main(self):
        while True:
            # using values from configFile here
            bla = self.conf.provideValues()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mc = MainClass()
    mc.main()
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a log of ways to do it; here's one:

```
class MyEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def hook(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
    def on_modified(self, event):
        super(MyEventHandler, self).on_modified(event)
        logging.info("File %s was just modified" % event.src_path)
        self.thing.readConfigFile()  #<- i want to call this method in class Configuration

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conf = Configuration()
        event_handler = MyEventHandler(patterns=patterns)
        event_handler.hook(self.conf)
```

Comment: thank, i actually found a way to do it, i initialized the eventhandler not by using a class but in the class itself so i could call the method within the class, but your way also worked, like you said, a lot of ways...